# Remy source code(github) compilation error in protobuf class

Tags: c++, c, networking, network-programming

I was trying to run Remy project(related to computer generated network protocols) source code using intructions as provided in this link;  https://github.com/tcpexmachina/remy. The code is also taken from this link.

I am using protobuf 3.5.1 version and Ubuntu version is 14.04. When I ran the 'make' command after running ./autogen.sh and ./configure respectively as instructed in the readme file, i received this error:

```
In file included from configrange.hh:4:0,
from evaluator.cc:3:
../protobufs/dna.pb.h:4210:20: error: base class ‘struct         
google::protobuf::internal::integral_constant<bool, true>’ has a    
non-virtual destructor [-Werror=effc++]
template <> struct is_proto_enum< ::RemyBuffers::MemoryRange_Axis> : 
::google::protobuf::internal::true_type {};
```

I looked at the issues section of the repository but it does not list any such error. Is it possible that the project used an older version of protobuf which caused this error? Also can someone explain what is the "-Werror=effc++" flag?
Please help me resolve this error if anyone has encountered this error before or has any experience with such issue.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag `-Weffc++` enables the warnings when your code violates any of style guidelines defined by Scott Meyers in his books (*Effective C++* series).
One of these guidelines tells that base class should have defined virtual destructor - and you got compiler message about it. Other guidelines are

> ```
>  Define a copy constructor and an assignment operator for classes with dynamically-allocated memory.
>  Prefer initialization to assignment in constructors.
>  Have operator= return a reference to *this.
>  Don’t try to return a reference when you must return an object.
>  Distinguish between prefix and postfix forms of increment and decrement operators.
>  Never overload &&, ||, or ,.
> ```

by enabling `-Weffc++` you would get only warnings, but what i see `-Werror` is defined too on compiler flags list. `-Werror`

> makes all warnings into errors

and your compilation was aborted. I think you should remove either `Weffc++` or `-Werror` from compiler flags list to compile your code.